# AngularJS - scope watch is not triggered athough ng-class has been updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement a dropdown mega-menu using Angular, where if the user clicks on Link 1, then the content for Link 1 should appear. My directives are as followed:

1. mobile-menu which acts as a controller and keeping track of the links and menu items states
2. menu-link, the actual link that user clicks on to open/close the menu items
3. menu-item, the menu item that should show/hide based on the scope.test value

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {})
.directive("mobileMenu", function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.menuLinks = [];
            this.menuItems = [];

            this.addMenuLink = function (l) {
                this.menuLinks.push(l);
            };
            this.addMenuItem = function (m) {
                this.menuItems.push(m);
            };
            // Function to close all other menu items if they are open.
            // This is because only one menu item can be active at a time
            this.closeOthers = function (selectedMenuLink) {

                angular.forEach(this.menuLinks, function (l) {
                    if (l !== selectedMenuLink) {
                        l.selected = false;
                    } 
                }); 

                angular.forEach(this.menuItems, function (m) {
                    if (selectedMenuLink.target == m.menuId) {
                        m.test = true;
                    } else {
                        m.test = false;
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
}).directive("menuLink", function () {
    return {
        require: "^mobileMenu",
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, menuController) {
                scope.selected = false;
        menuController.addMenuLink(scope);

        scope.$watch('selected', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (oldValue === newValue) {return};

            if (newValue) {
                scope.target = angular.element(element[0].children[0]).attr("data-menu");
                menuController.closeOthers(scope);
            }
         });
       }
    };
}).directive("menuItem", function () {
    return {
        require: "^mobileMenu",
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, menuController) {

            scope.test = false;
            scope.menuId = attrs.id;
            menuController.addMenuItem(scope);

            scope.$watch('test', watchLink);
            scope.$watch(attrs.collapse, watchLink);
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.test;
            }, watchLink);

            var watchLink = function (newValue, oldValue) {

                // Initializing for the first time, do nothing
                if (newValue === oldValue) return;


                // If the collapse attribute has a true value, collapse this element
                if (newValue) {
                    collapse();
                } else {
                    expand();
                }
            };

            // Helper function to collapse the element
            var collapse = function () {
                element.css({
                    height: "0px"
                });
            };

            // Helper function to show the element
            var expand = function () {
                element.css({
                    height: "200px"
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div mobile-menu>
    <ul> 
        <li menu-link>
            <a href="#" ng-click="selected = !selected" ng-class="{'expanded' : selected, 'collapsed' : !selected}" data-menu="menu0">Link 1</a>
        </li>

         <li menu-link>
             <a href="#" ng-click="selected = !selected" ng-class="{'expanded' : selected, 'collapsed' : !selected}" data-menu="menu1">Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="menu0" ng-class="{'expanded' : test, 'collapsed' : !test}" menu-item collapse="!test">
        <p class="text">First Menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" ng-class="{'expanded' : test, 'collapsed' : !test}" menu-item collapse="!test">
        <p class="promo-text">Second Menu</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an issue where if menu-link #1 is clicked, the corresponding menu-item #1's scope.test value should be updated and its' scope watch should be triggered, but it does not. If the scope watch triggered the watchLink function, then I would expect menu-item #1 would have a height of 200px.

I have also attached a jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EmwBP/28/

If you look at the browser console tool, the corresponding menu-item ng-class is always updated based on its scope.test value. However, even with my 3 different scope watchers set up, none of them were triggered. I am also using the ng-class directive just to show that the scope.test value does get updated and will be removed in the final implementation.

Normally, I would have put the menu-item directives as a child of menu-links, but I have a requirement where I have to put the menu-items as it is right now to achieve the slide-down effect of pushing elements below it down.

Many thanks in advance for your advices and assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You create a new isolated scope in `menuLink` by using `scope: {}`. So whatever scope variables you set inside that scope (like `selected`) are only available within that scope, and will not propagate to sibling or parent scopes.</del>

<del>What you need to do is de-isolate the `menuLink` scope by using `scope: true`.</del>

---

That is not the problem. The problem is that `watchLink` is used before you define it. Fix where `watchLink` is triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/EmwBP/31/

Comment: Hi, I created a new isolated scope as I would be using ng-repeat and data-binding to create the menuLink directives in the future. I was hoping that by calling the controller's closeOthers() to update/trigger menuItems' scope test values. Would that not work?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I hadn't looked properly at your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thanks for the help :)